# Multiplying text put value with the sum of check box values and display it on paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to multiply the entered text input value with the sum of check box values clicked. So far when you click the check boxes the sumof their avues is displayed instantly on the span emlement with id="Totalcost". How can I multiply the sum of the checkbox selected with the value entered in the text input field.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var total = 0;
     inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
    function test(item){
 var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');
      if(item.checked){
           total+= parseInt(item.value);
        }else{
           total-= parseInt(item.value);
        }
        //alert(total);
        document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total ;
    }

</script>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 
  </head>
  <body>
<input type="text"  id="chatinput" onchange="myFunction()"><br>
<p id="printchatbox"></p>
    <div id="container">
    <p id="printc"></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="channcost" value="10" onClick="test(this);"  />10<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="20" onClick="test(this);" />20 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chancost" value="40" onClick="test(this);" />40 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="60" onClick="test(this);" />60 <br />
    </div>
    Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span><BR><BR><BR>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So are you wanting a user to enter a number in 'chatinput', and then to multiple that number against the total value of the checkbox's that are checked?

Comment: Yes, Tha'ts exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function test(item) {
  var operand1 = parseFloat($('#chatinput').val());
  var operand2 = 0;
  var result;

  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    operand2 += parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
  });

  // operand1 could be NaN
  // you need to decide what to do in that case
  result = operand1 * operand2;

  $('#Totalcost').html(result);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="chatinput" onchange="test()">
  <br>
  <p id="printchatbox"></p>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="printc"></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="channcost" value="10" onclick="test()" />10
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="20" onclick="test()" />20
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chancost" value="40" onclick="test()" />40
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="60" onclick="test()" />60
    <br />
  </div>
  Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot....it works great...Just incase you need this, below is the code for the JQuery Version that works with this too.    http://evansonmwakio.com/test3.html

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, something like this may work.

When a checkbox is clicked, it will calculate the **total** of all checkboxes, multiply that against the users input, and output it.

```
// When a checkbox is clicked
$('#container input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    // Get user input and set initial variable for the total
    inputBox = parseInt($('#chatinput').val());
    totalCheckbox = 0;
    // itterate through each checkbox
    // If it's checked, add the current value to total
    $('#container input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            thisValue = parseInt($(this).val());
            totalCheckbox = totalCheckbox + thisValue;
        }
    });
    // Output the total checkbox value multipled against user input
    $('#Totalcost').html(total * inputBox);    
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2mdrshp/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to multiply the entered text input value with the check box value and add the total sum clicked.

```
<html>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item0" value="5" />First(5)
<input id="a" type="text" name="qty0" />
 <br/>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item1" value="7" />Second(7)
 <input id="a" type="text" name="qty1" />
 <br/>
 <input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item2" value="10" />Third(10)
 <br/>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item2" value="8"  />Fourth(8)
<br/> Total Price: $<span id="price" class="price">0</span>

<script>
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('selectproduct'),
price = document.getElementById('price');

for (var i=0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].onchange = function() {
        var inputBox = document.getElementById('a');
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total = add*parseInt(this.value);

        price.innerHTML = parseFloat(price.innerHTML)+total
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```